# Unity yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a script allowing to go up the value of the player's stamina after 2 seconds. My code works perfectly without the WaitForSeconds, but suddenly the rise of the stamina is done instantly and that's not what I want. So I added the WaitForSeconds but nothing helps, it doesn't work.

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            currentstamina -= 1f;

            if(currentstamina <= 0)
            {
                currentstamina = 0;
                runningSpeed = walkingSpeed;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) == false)
        {
            if (currentstamina < 20)
            {
                if (regen != null)
                    StopCoroutine(regen);
                regen = StartCoroutine(StaminaBack());
            }
        }

        IEnumerator StaminaBack()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

            while(currentstamina < startingstamina)
            {
                currentstamina += startingstamina / 100;
                yield return regenTick;
            }
            regen = null;
        }
```

Thank you in advance for the help you will provide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming this code is run in an update loop, you're currently cancelling the coroutine every frame while not running.

Ie. if shift, lose stamina, else, cancel regen, and start regen

I presume you're after something more like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    if (regen != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(regen);
        regen = null;
    }

    currentStamina -= 1f;

    if (currentstamina <= 0)
    {
        currentstamina = 0;
        runningSpeed = walkingSpeed;
    }
}
else if (regen == null && stamina < 20)
{
    regen = StartCoroutine(StaminaBack());
}
```

Ie. if shift, cancel regen and lose stamina, else, start regen (if not already started)